# How to pattern match types in Scala macros?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

I have a method in my project with macros (whitebox), trying to verify and extract type arguments from a return type of a `MethodSymbol`.
Here is the code (placed inside some class with `import c.universe._`):

```
private object ImplMethod {
  def apply(m: MethodSymbol): ImplMethod = {

    println(m.returnType)

    val respType = m.returnType match {
      case tq"scala.concurrent.Future[scala.util.Either[String, ${resp}]]" => resp
      case _ =>
        c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"Method ${m.name} in type ${m.owner} does not have required result type Future[Either[String, ?]]")
    }


    ???
  }
}
```

During the compilation it says `Warning:scalac: scala.concurrent.Future[Either[String, Int]]` which is right, however right after that it stops on the `c.abort` call which means the pattern doesn't match the type.

I even tried to debug it in REPL, but here is what I got:

```
val tq"scala.concurrent.Future[$a]" = typeOf[scala.concurrent.Future[Int]]

scala.MatchError: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] (of class 
scala.reflect.internal.Types$ClassArgsTypeRef)
  ... 28 elided
```

I tried this many times already but always ended up with handling those types as `String`s which is very unclear.
Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 2):

I'd be grateful if someone showed an example of deconstructing `Type` using quasiquotes and pattern-matching. For now it seems to me that `Type` and quasiquotes are parts of different universes (not in Scala internals sense) and can't interact. The best way I know to do something like this is code like this:

```
val string = typeOf[String].dealias
val future = typeOf[scala.concurrent.Future[_]].typeConstructor
val either = typeOf[scala.util.Either[_, _]].typeConstructor

val respType = (for {
  f <- Some(m.returnType.dealias) if f.typeConstructor == future // Future[_]
  e <- f.typeArgs.headOption if e.typeConstructor == either // Future[Either[_,_]]
  ea <- Some(e.typeArgs) if ea.head.dealias == string // Future[Either[String,_]]
} yield ea(1))
  .getOrElse(c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"Method ${m.name} in type ${m.owner} does not have required result type Future[Either[String, ?]]"))
```

I use `Some` to wrap `Type` into `Option` and use for-comprehension syntax that IMHO makes it easier to understand what's going on, much easier than what you could get if you tried to use usual (non-quasiquotes-based) pattern matching on `Type`.

---

**Update: Where `tq""` works at all?`**

From my experience the only context in which you can use `tq""` to deconstruct type is in [Macro annotations](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html) that can be used to annotate whole classes or method definitions. Consider following example:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.Either

class Test {

  @CheckReturnTypeMacroAnnotation
  def foo1(): scala.concurrent.Future[scala.util.Either[String, Short]] = ???

  @CheckReturnTypeMacroAnnotation
  def foo2(): Future[Either[String, Int]] = ???

  @CheckReturnTypeMacroAnnotation
  def foo3(): scala.concurrent.Future[Either[String, Long]] = ???

  @CheckReturnTypeMacroAnnotation
  def foo4(): Future[scala.util.Either[String, Double]] = ???

  @CheckReturnTypeMacroAnnotation
  def fooBad()  = scala.concurrent.Future.failed[scala.util.Either[String, Short]](new RuntimeException("Fake"))

}
```

We want `CheckReturnTypeMacroAnnotation` to ensure that the return type is of form `scala.concurrent.Future[scala.util.Either[String, ?]]`. We may implement `CheckReturnTypeMacroAnnotation` as

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.annotation.{StaticAnnotation, compileTimeOnly}


@compileTimeOnly("enable macro to expand macro annotations")
class CheckReturnTypeMacroAnnotation extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*) = macro CheckReturnTypeMacro.process
}


object CheckReturnTypeMacro {

  import scala.reflect.macros._
  import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context

  def process(c: Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._
    val methodDef = annottees.map(_.tree).toList match {
      case x :: Nil => x
      case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Method definition is expected")
    }
    //c.warning(c.enclosingPosition, s"methodDef ${methodDef.getClass} => $methodDef")

    val returnType = methodDef match {
      case q"$mods def $name[..$tparams](...$paramss): $tpt = $body" => tpt
      case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Method definition is expected")
    }
    //c.warning(NoPosition, s"returnType ${returnType.getClass} => $returnType")

    val respType = returnType match {
      case tq"scala.concurrent.Future[scala.util.Either[String, ${resp}]]" =>
        c.warning(c.enclosingPosition, s"1 resp ${resp.getClass} => $resp")
        resp
      case tq"Future[Either[String, ${resp}]]" =>
        c.warning(c.enclosingPosition, s"2 resp ${resp.getClass} => $resp")
        resp
      case tq"scala.concurrent.Future[Either[String, ${resp}]]" =>
        c.warning(c.enclosingPosition, s"3 resp ${resp.getClass} => $resp")
        resp
      case tq"Future[scala.util.Either[String, ${resp}]]" =>
        c.warning(c.enclosingPosition, s"4 resp ${resp.getClass} => $resp")
        resp

      case _ =>
        c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"Method does not have required result type Future[Either[String, ?]]")
    }

    c.Expr[Any](methodDef) //this is in fact a no-op macro. it only does verification of return type
  }
}
```

Note however how you have to handle various cases with different but similar `tq""` patterns and that `fooBad` that does not explicitly specify return type will fail anyway. The output of an attempt to compile `Test` with this macro will generate an output like this:

```
Warning:(18, 8) 1 resp class scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Ident => Short
      @CheckReturnTypeMacroAnnotation
Warning:(21, 8) 2 resp class scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Ident => Int
      @CheckReturnTypeMacroAnnotation
Warning:(24, 8) 3 resp class scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Ident => Long
      @CheckReturnTypeMacroAnnotation
Warning:(27, 8) 4 resp class scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Ident => Double
      @CheckReturnTypeMacroAnnotation
Error:(31, 8) Method does not have required result type Future[Either[String, ?]]
      @CheckReturnTypeMacroAnnotation
```

Note how all 4 cases actually present in the output and that `fooBad` has failed. The issue seems to come from the fact that macro is run before typechecker. Unfortunately I'm not aware of a way to make this pattern matching really work. I looked into `reify` and `c.typecheck` but had no luck.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is an alternative way how to decompose it, you're right an I forgot to mention it. However it's too verbose :-/ I found many links like https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/type-details.html or  https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/pattern-details.html bit didn't help too much.

Comment: @jenda, My current (possible wrong) understanding is that quasiquotes are used to construct/deconstruct `Tree`s rather than `Type`s. And that's why your code doesn't work and probably can't be made to work. See also https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/terminology.html

Comment: Well what are `tq` and other _interpolators_ for then? :-) Maybe @TravisBrown or @eugene-burmako could explain.. Please? :-)

Comment: @jenda, I've added an update about my experience and it is far from encouraging. I would also appreciate to learn that my experience can be improved by knowing the right tricks.